# IDEA. Get "bad variable name" when run tests on WSL

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I try to run tests by IDEA on WSL 2.0, but I get the next error

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper /mnt/c/Users/gagar/AppData/Local/Temp/idea_classpath60908778 com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.tests.rest.agent.Agent
/bin/sh: 1: export: ProgramFiles(x86): bad variable name

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: Having the same issue, any fix without the Toolbox method?

Answer (score 0):

Installed IDEA via Toolbox. Now it's going okay. The difference is the path to IDEA.